# VB6, CDate(sheet.range("B", counter))

Tags: excel, vb6

I've been looking and looking for a solution but without success.
I need to populate list-view by date criteria, I know how to fill it with simple criteria but date criteria has given me a lot of problems.

I have dates (dd.mm.yyyy) in B column in my Excel document and I need to convert them to date and compare with date which I choose from calendar control on the form. How can I set that default date in VB6 be dd.mm.yyyy?
I am beginner and I don't know where I am wrong, please help me. Thanks in advance.

```vb
Do Until .Cells(myCounter, 1) & "" = ""
  strDate = listObj.Range("B" & myCounter)
  myDate= CDate(strDate) >>>>>>>>>> Run-time error "13" Mismatch type
  If myDate > Calendar1.Value Then
    .........................
  End If
  myCounter =myCounter + 1
Loop
```

edit: This is my whole code

```
    Dim excelObj As excel.Application
    Dim wbObj As excel.Workbook
    Dim sheetObj As Worksheet
    Dim myCounter As Long
    Set excelObj = New excel.Application
    excelObj.Visible = False
    Set wbObj = excelObj.Workbooks.Open(App.Path & "\excel_document.xlsx")
    Set sheetObj = excelObj.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim L As ListItem
    Dim myDateAs Date
    Dim strDate As String
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
    With sheetObj
    myCounter = 2
    Do Until .Cells(myCounter, 1) & "" = ""
    strDate = sheetObj.Range("B" & myCounter)
    myDate= CDate(strDate)
    If myDate > Calendar1.Value Then
    ........
    End If
    myCounter = myCounter + 1
    Loop
    End With
    excelObj.Quit
```

In excel document B column is formatted as Date - dd/mm/yyyy. I tried also not to do CDate but without success.

Comment: Does `myCounter` have a value entering the loop? What is the value of `strDate` when the 3rd line blows up? Is `.` the date separator character that Excel/VBA is expecting? Also what's the question exactly, do you have the `.............` part figured out or you're asking about the type mismatch?

Comment: Starting value of myCounter is 2 cause first row is header of table in excel and strDate has the cell value for example strDate = 31.05.2013 and strDate changes as the loop doing its bussiness. I have all figured out, only CDate is bugging me. This is just fragment of my whole function. My question is, is CDate the right way to convert cell value (for example cell B2 has the value 31.12.2013) to Date format in VB6? And, do I need to format default date format in VB6 somehow?

Comment: Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

Comment: In Excel separator between numbers of date is "." - dot example:25.12.2013 , and in VB6 default separator is "/" - divide sign example: 25/12/2013 
My only question is about mismatch. Sorry for spamming you, I tried to explain you my problem as much as I can.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake.  I misread part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

How did you declare `strDate`? `Dim strDate As String`? Variant? Not declared?

Given what you're trying to do, it really should be declared as either Variant or Date. It looks like you declared it as a String, and that you are also entering strings on the cells.

When you Enter the date values in Excel, you should enter them as dates instead of strings. It's easy; just make sure that the cells are formatted with "dd.mm.yyyy" and they will accept such dates correctly when you type them. When you retrieve the values from VB, they will be retrieved as Dates and you will be able to manipulate them as such.

If you really want to transform a string that comes in  that format into a `Date` value, you can use this method: [Parse finnish date string to Date Type in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399164)